# CropViewHelper show HTML tags

Tags: typo3, view-helpers, typo3-9.x

I'm using format.crop ViewHelper in the template to crop the text.

The problem that the output display HTML tags :

#### ViewHelper :

```
<f:format.crop maxCharacters="250" respectHtml="false">{book.description}</f:format.crop>
```

#### Output HTML :

```
 <p>This is <p> and </p> HTML tags appears</p>
```

I tried both `respectHtml="false"` and `respectHtml="true"` but it's not works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fluid by default escapes HTML to prevent Cross Site Scripting vulnerability.

This is by design. Integrators need to disable this behavior for specific areas. This can be done by using `f:format.html` or `f:format.raw`, while `raw` will prevent all security mechanisms and should therefore be used very rarely.

`format.html` does apply another configuration which defines which HTML tags and attributes are allowed: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Parsefunc.html

You concrete example could be:

```
<f:format.html>
    <f:format.crop maxCharacters="250" respectHtml="1">
        {book.description}
    </f:format.crop>
</f:format.html>
```

Or:

```
<f:format.raw>
    <f:format.crop maxCharacters="250" respectHtml="1">
        {book.description}
    </f:format.crop>
</f:format.raw>
```

If preferred, you could also use the inline notation:

```
{book.description -> f:format.crop(maxCharacters: 250, respectHtml: true) -> f:format.html()}
```

I would recommend to respect HTML, otherwise HTML might be broken, as closing tags might be cut off.

In case you do not want HTML output at all, use `f:format.stripTags` before applying `f:format.crop`, in order to remove HTML tags beforehand.

Comment: I tried the three suggestions and yes, work exactly as I hope, thanks @Daniel for all informations and for help :)